# What is the easiest way to insert Data into a mysql DB with C++?

Tags: c++, mysql

1. Do i need external libraries ?
2. is there any minimalistic example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the C API which is usually installed along with the MySQL Server. On Windows, for example, it's in "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0" (see "include" and "lib" directory).

> If you are looking for examples that demonstrate how to use the C API, take a look at these clients. You can find these in the client directory in the MySQL source distribution.

The client API is called `mysqlclient`, you can find the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c.html).

But you can also use other libraries like the [C++ wrapper on sourceforge](http://mysqlcppapi.sourceforge.net/). Or an ODBC abstraction like contained in cross-platform toolkits (e.g. wxDb in wxWidgets).